# Not sure where I went wrong on a sql join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

The most programming I do is shell scripts or some python or perl, so I have a basic understanding after Googling for a bit. A little background on what i’m doing. We have two inventory systems: Our’s and Their’s. I need to pull information from Their’s to compare with Our’s.

The problem: We need UPC’s to do inventory while They provide SKU’s in their monthly inventory report.

The solution: Join 3 tables. I’m using phpmyadmin to manage a mysql backend on a recent install of Debain Wheezy.

The first query takes every SKU They have in Their inventory, compares it with the UPC in Their listings and, since not every ‘UPC’ is actually a UPC, compares it to the UPC in Our listings. It looks like this:

```
SELECT TheirListings.upc,  SUM(TheirInventory.quantity)
FROM TheirInventory
JOIN TheirListings
ON TheirListings.sku =  TheirInventory.sku
JOIN OurListings
ON TheirListings.upc = OurListings.Upc
GROUP BY TheirListings.upc
ORDER BY TheirListings.upc
```

And it seems to work well. Our system is happy with it and it makes me happy because this reduces manual entry by 96%. Now I need to get everything this didn’t catch: the 4% that does need manual entry. Our tables shortened for brevity like this:

```
TheirListings       TheirInventory      OurListings
upc                 sku                 upc
sku                 quantity
```

I need to select all the SKU’s and associated quantities:

```
SELECT TheirInventory.sku,  SUM(TheirInventory.quantity)
FROM  TheirInventory
LEFT OUTER JOIN TheirListings
ON TheirListings.sku =  TheirInventory.sku
LEFT OUTER JOIN OurListings
ON TheirListings.upc = OurListings.upc
WHERE OurListings.upc IS NULL
OR TheirListings.upc IS NULL
GROUP BY TheirInventory.sku
ORDER BY TheirInventory.sku
```

To double check it’s catching the remainder, I did SELECT COUNT(TheirInventory.sku) for both of those queries and another to return the total of sku’s. Adding my two queries gives me exactly 1 more than expected. I’m not sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would guess is that they're not working on the same datasets.  If you ran the first one a few days ago, perhaps some data has changed causing it to show up in the second query?

If not, what I would do is

```
SELECT SKU
FROM TheirInventory
WHERE SKU IN (<1st query>)
  AND SKU IN (<2nd query>)
```

This will tell you what is showing up in both, and you can diagnose from there.

Comment: This is a fresh data set. We get these reports monthly. I exported new data from both Our's and Their's Listings earlier today. I'll try this though.

Comment: My poor desktop! I'll run this query on much better hardware soon.

Comment: I ran the query. Unfortunately It returned an empty result. I'll have to live with the small amount of error